# MySQL finding many children of one parent

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

If I have a relationship between two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (id INT NOT NULL, parent_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
);
```

And I want to find all of the rows in the child table that are referencing one row in the parent table, is it faster to:

1. Simply query the child table and return all that match the id of the parent row
2. Store a comma separated list of ids in a column in the parent table
3. None of the above

Comment: do you also want to find deeper level of children?

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: @JW yes the child table will have children that may need to reference the parent (now grandparent) table

Comment: Adding a `FOREIGN KEY` [implicitly adds an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), and returning all rows that matches an index is generally fast enough. You'll probably need to run a benchmark to see if (1) or (2) is faster, but, as Bill Karwin pointed out, (2) is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key is naturally indexed, so the best way to go is to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent_id=X;
-- where X is the parent's ID
```